# Makefile error: "install 'filename' was not found anywhere!"

Tags: ant, makefile, installation, relative-path

I am attempting to make a project and have run into this error when trying to issue an install command on a handful of executables.  Looks something like this:

```
(in highest level dir:)
DIRS = \
       dir1 \
       dir2 \
       ... \
       lastDir \

all clean release:
    for x in $(DIRS); do cd $$x; make $@; cd ..; done
```

Then in dir1, for example:

```
all: $(PROG)
    install $(PROG) ../../bin
```

and the same for each directory.  Log looks like this:

```
[exec] install my_prog_name ../../bin
[exec] install: my_prog_name was not found anywhere!
[exec] make[1]: Leaving dir1
```

Neither makefile (in upper or lower directory) has been changed since the last successful build, same with the build file (using ant).

Kind of looks like either a pathing issue or a permissions issue.  Permissions on destination directory are 777, though.  Issuing the install command manually in dir1 works fine...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How about `cd dir1; make all`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this on Solaris?  It seems the Solaris version of the **install** command is prone to generate this error.

I'm not sure what the root cause is, but you could try using **/usr/ucb/install**, plain **cp** or the GNU **ginstall**.